# List of Strings to separate sets

Tags: python, list, set

So I am having problems with a problem. I have to write a function that turns a list of strings( I don't know how many strings will be in the list as there are different test cases with different lists) into separate sets. I have to do this because I want to use the symmetric difference property of sets on the produced sets later on. For instance how would I convert this list of strings into four separate sets?

```
(["zebra bear fox elephant", "bear crocodile fox", "rhino elephant crocodile kangaroo", "elephant bear"])
```

Please remember that I will not know the number of strings in each list and must find a general solution that holds for all.

Comment: Separate sets of what? Characters? Words? Meteors?

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward list comprehension:

```
[set(x.split()) for x in my_list]
```

(assuming you want words as the elements of your sets)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please tell me how I can access the created sets in order to evaluate their symmetric difference?

Comment: The sets will be in a list, so if  `s = [set(x.split()) for x in my_list]`, then the first set is `s[0]`, the second `s[1]` and so on.

Comment: Yes I realize that, but like i said, I do not know how many strings there are in the original list of strings so I can't really use indices here.

Comment: @user2904796 iterate over them.